# re.sub replacing string using original sub-string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file. I would like to remove all decimal points and their trailing numbers, unless text is preceding.

e.g 12.29,14.6,8967.334 should be replaced with 12,14,8967

e.g happypants2.3@email.com should not be modified.

My code is:

```
import re

txt1 = "9.9,8.8,22.2,88.7,morris1.43@email.com,chat22.3@email.com,123.6,6.54"
txt1 = re.sub(r',\d+[.]\d+', r'\d+',txt1)
print(txt1)
```

unless there is an easier way of completing this, how do I modify r'\d+' so it just returns the number without a decimal place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of groups in your regex. You put the digits before the '.' into parentheses, and then you can use `'\1'` to refer to them later:

```
txt1 = re.sub(r',(\d+)[.]\d+', r',\1',txt1)
```

Note that in your attempted replacement code you forgot to replace the comma, so your numbers would have been glommed together. This still isn't perfect though; the first number, since it doesn't begin with a comma, isn't processed.

Instead of checking for a comma, the better way is to check word boundaries, which can be done using `\b`. So the solution is:

```
import re

txt1 = "9.9,8.8,22.2,88.7,morris1.43@email.com,chat22.3@email.com,123.6,6.54"
txt1 = re.sub(r'\b(\d+)[.]\d+\b', r'\1',txt1)
print(txt1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering these are the only two types of string that is present in your file, you can explicitly check for these conditions.

This may not be an efficient way, but what I have done is split the `str` and check if the string contains `@email.com`. If thats true, I am just appending to a new list. For your 1st condition to satisfy, we can convert the `str` to `int` which will eliminate the decimal points.

If you want everything back to a str variable, you can use `.join()`.

**Code:**

```
txt1 = "9.9,8.8,22.2,88.7,morris1.43@email.com,chat22.3@email.com,123.6,6.54"
txt_list = []
for i in (txt1.split(',')):
    if '@email.com' in i:
        txt_list.append(i)
    else:
        txt_list.append(str(int(float(i))))

txt_new = ",".join(txt_list)
txt_new
```

**Output:**

```
'9,8,22,88,morris1.43@email.com,chat22.3@email.com,123,6'
```